# How to access to Form components from another class

Tags: c++, winforms

I have WinForm and a class, I am trying to set text to Form component from class, but it let me access any components when calling from class, even if this components are declared as public. Any ideas why this is not working? Would be very thankful, I am sorry if this stupid question, I am kind of noob. Thank you!

**OpenGL_on_a_Windows_Form.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"


using namespace OpenGL_on_a_Windows_Form;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}
```

**Form1.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "OpenGL.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

namespace OpenGL_on_a_Windows_Form {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace OpenGLForm;
    using namespace System::Diagnostics;
    using namespace System::IO;


    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {

    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OpenGL = gcnew COpenGL(splitContainer1->Panel2, splitContainer1->Panel2->Width, splitContainer1->Panel2->Height);

        }

    protected:
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^ components;
    protected:
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Timer^ timer1;
    public: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ MessageLog;

    private:

        OpenGLForm::COpenGL^ OpenGL;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        

        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^ resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form1::typeid));
            this->timer1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer(this->components));
            this->splitContainer1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::SplitContainer());
            this->splitContainer2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::SplitContainer());

            this->MessageLog = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            //....etc

            // MessageLog
            // 
            this->MessageLog->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Fill;
            this->MessageLog->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
            this->MessageLog->Multiline = true;
            this->MessageLog->Name = L"MessageLog";
            this->MessageLog->ReadOnly = true;
            this->MessageLog->Size = System::Drawing::Size(140, 261);
            this->MessageLog->TabIndex = 0;
            this->MessageLog->Text = L"Message Log:";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(1183, 674);
            //....etc

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
    {
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(sender);
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(e);
        OpenGL->Render();

    }


};
}
```

**OpenGL.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include "lib.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>



using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;



namespace OpenGLForm
{
    public ref class COpenGL : public System::Windows::Forms::NativeWindow
    {



    public:


        COpenGL(System::Windows::Forms::SplitterPanel^ parentForm, GLsizei iWidth, GLsizei iHeight)
        {
            CreateParams^ cp = gcnew CreateParams;

            cp->X = 5;
            cp->Y = 5;
            cp->Width = parentForm->Height - 5;
            cp->Height = parentForm->Width - 5;


            cp->Parent = parentForm->Handle;

            cp->Style = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_DISABLED;

            this->CreateHandle(cp);

            m_hDC = GetDC((HWND)this->Handle.ToPointer());

            if (m_hDC)
            {
                MySetPixelFormat(m_hDC);
            }

        }


        System::Void Render(System::Void)
        {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

        }


    private:
        HDC m_hDC;
        HGLRC m_hglrc;
        GLfloat rtri;               
        GLfloat rquad;          

    protected:
        ~COpenGL(System::Void)
        {
            this->DestroyHandle();
        }

        GLint MySetPixelFormat(HDC hdc)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        void set_text()
        {
            Form1::MessageLog::Text = "some text"; //---Problem is here, Form1 is not a class or numspace name

        }



    };

    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set_text` function needs to use a specific `Form` **object**, like this

```
    void set_text()
    {
        mainForm->MessageLog->Text = "some text"; 
    }
```

To make this work, `mainForm` needs to be a member variable of `COpenGL` of type `System::Windows::Forms::Form^`, and this member should be initialized in the constructor (resulting in a constructor call like this):

```
    OpenGL = gcnew COpenGL(this, splitContainer1->Panel2, splitContainer1->Panel2->Width, splitContainer1->Panel2->Height);
```

Alternatively, instead of passing the whole `Form` object to the `COpenGL` object, just pass a reference to the message log and store it in a member variable. Something along the lines of

```
public ref class COpenGL : public System::Windows::Forms::NativeWindow
{

   System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ messageLog;

   public:
   
   COpenGL( System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ messageLog,
       System::Windows::Forms::SplitterPanel^ parentForm, 
       GLsizei iWidth, GLsizei iHeight)
    {
        this->messageLog=messageLog;
        // ...
    }

    void set_text()
    {
       messageLog->Text = "some text"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Doc Brown, thank you for you answer, indeed inside COpenGL I can access to messageLog object if I pass it like `COpenGL(System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ messageLog, System::Windows::Forms::SplitterPanel^ parentForm, GLsizei iWidth, GLsizei iHeight)`. But outside this function(?) I still cannot access to this object. For example set_text() function in code above is outside COpenGL.

Comment: @RuslanIbragimov: you seem to have overlooked the part in my answer where I wrote "you need to make it a member variable of this class and assign it inside the constructor". I will add some code to make it more clear.

Comment: yes, that worked magnificently! Thank you and all people who answers questions, you doing amazing job.

Answer (score 0):

Class.cs:
public void Function(Form form)
{
form.component.something();
}
In Form class:
...
Class class = new Class();
class.Function(this);
...